# How do I programmatically make it so that SAS doesn't print to Results?

Tags: sas

I am running some proc and using ods output FitStatistics = fs; etc to create some SAS datasets from the outputs. But since I am running it a large number of times, I want to suppress the printing to Results. What's is the SAS code for doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked and answered a while ago on runsubmit.com.  It's like stackoverflow but just for SAS related q's.

http://www.runsubmit.com/questions/248/suppressing-results-output-with-proc-print-and-ods

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 0):

How about use the codes at below:

```
ods _all_ close;
ods output FitStatistics = fs
```